# bitmap always returning null in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, null, gallery

I've been trying to make a small gallery and the bitmaps are always returning null. The code is like this:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),imgArray2.length+ " Image path from gallery : " + imgArray2[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArray2[position]);
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse(imgArray2[position]);
        //Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(new File(uri.toString()).getAbsoluteFile());
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.toString());
        //int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(path, "drawable", "mypack.pack");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 15;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgArray2[position], options);
        //i.setImageResource(imgArray2[position]);
        i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse(imgArray2[position]);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image path from gallery : " + imgArray2[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //i.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgArray2[position]));
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(170, 170));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return i; 
   }
```

As you can see by the commented out code, I've been trying many option. `setImageURI` works but I need to scale down the image as I have many. The images are in the sd card. I checked the path of image and it is correct. What am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you analyze the logs? Sometimes when images are too big to decode, the Dalvik VM will deny a memory request resulting in a null image being returned.

Comment: How can i scale it down then? Even if i have low res pics, it still returns null